# linux cat files in a folder after specific date piped with awk

Tags: linux, date, awk, hdfs, cat

I have thousands of files in a folder and I have to cat files starting with specified test. But I have files starting with same text but with different dates, I have to print (*cat*) the files with the specified starting text after my mentioned date.

```
hdfs dfs -cat /tmp/folder1/region_1101_*_summary_*/part* | awk '$1 == "NumOfMissingIds" {print $2}'
```

Expecting suggestions to combine date part to the command.

Comment: I would not use awk for date comparison but Python which seems more suited for this problem.

Comment: **possibility of having multiple folder created in different date/time **  stating with region_1101* . So any possibility to get file contents with the mentioned search term (NumOfMissingIds) in each file (part*) under the path /tmp/folder1/region_1101__summary_ after certain created date/time. @Serge Ballesta

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like that:

```
awk 'BEGIN {out = 0} 
  /startpattern/ {out = 1}
  $1 == "NumOfMissingIds" { if (out) print $2 }'
```

Comment: possibility of having multiple folder created in different date/time stating with region_1101* . So any possibility to get file contents with the mentioned search term (NumOfMissingIds) in each file (part*)  under  the path /tmp/folder1/region_1101_*_summary_*  after certain created date/time.